# this.hide() in AngularJS ng-click

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a list of buttons in one page same like List View, I want to hide that specific button which was clicked.

This is what I tried.

```
<input type="button" ng-click="add_item_to_list()" class="add-item-to-list" value="Add This Item" />

$scope.add_item_to_list= function(e) {
    jQuery(this).hide();
};
```

How can this be done in AngularJS? Specifically is there a way like we use `this` in jQuery?

Comment: why does not use ng-hide directive?

Comment: How do you create this list of buttons? Manually or using ng-repeat?

Comment: @SSH Actually I want to hide that specific button and apply some opacity on it's parent div. so it's easy for user to see how much Items he added in list. That's why I need 'this' same like we use in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have multiple buttons which need the same behaviour, using scope variables is not good. Consider using the Angular directive for this:

```js
var myApp = angular.module("sa", []);
myApp.directive('clickToHide', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.on("click", function() {
        element.addClass("ng-hide");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa">


  <input type="button" ng-click="add_item_to_list()" class="add-item-to-list" value="Add This Item 1" click-to-hide />


  <input type="button" ng-click="add_item_to_list()" class="add-item-to-list" value="Add This Item 2" click-to-hide />

</div>
```

This way, you don't have to use the jQuery at all.

### Note

From the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

> If jQuery is available, `angular.element` is an alias for the jQuery
>   function. If jQuery is not available, `angular.element` delegates to
>   Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or **jqLite**.
>
> jqLite is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows Angular
>   to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. jqLite
>   implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the goal
>   of having a very small footprint.

Comment: "This way, you don't have to use the jQuery at all.", you realise that `element.on` is a jQuery function right? As well as `addClass`

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Yes, both `.on` and `.addClass` is a jQuery function but are also available in Angular (without jQuery). They kept the same name to support Angular with jQuery. If jQuery is available, the jQuery selector will be used else a jQlite selector will be used.

Comment: Was just about to say it could need some clarification, +1

Answer (score 1):

A really simple solution with the build in `ng-hide` directive:

```
<input type="button" class="add-item-to-list" value="Add This Item"
       ng-click="add_item_to_list()"
       ng-hide="hideItem" />

$scope.add_item_to_list= function(e) {
    $scope.hideItem = true;
}
```

If you use it in an `ng-repeat`, do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="button" class="add-item-to-list" value="Add This Item"
           ng-click="add_item_to_list(item)"
           ng-hide="item.added" />
</div>

$scope.add_item_to_list= function(item) {
    item.added = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use [`ngHide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) directive

> The `ngHide` directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the `expression` provided to the `ngHide` attribute.

*HTML*

```
<input type="button" ng-hide="hideDiv" ng-click="add_item_to_list()" class="add-item-to-list" value="Add This Item" />
```

*Script*

```
$scope.hideDiv= false;
$scope.add_item_to_list= function(e) {
    $scope.hideDiv= true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" 
       ng-show="isVisible" 
       ng-click="add_item_to_list()" 
       class="add-item-to-list" 
       value="Add This Item" />

$scope.isVisible = true;

$scope.add_item_to_list= function(e) {
    $scope.isVisible = false;
}
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use ng-hide:

```
<input type="button" ng-hide="hideItem" ng-click="add_item_to_list() hideItem=True" class="add-item-to-list" value="Add This Item" />
```

This could be run as a variable like above, or in your function by including the function inside the ng-hide parameter.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<html>
<head> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

    <input id="input1" type="button" ng-click="add_item_to_list()" ng-model="name" ng-hide="hideIt" />

<script>
//Module Declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngMessages']);
//Controller Declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.hideIt = false;
    $scope.add_item_to_list = function(){
        $scope.hideIt = true;
    }
});
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```